# How to create a heterogeneous Python dict in Rust with PyO3?

Tags: rust, pyo3

Based on [this](https://pyo3.rs/master/python_from_rust.html) I can create a homogeneous Python dictionary.

How can I create a dictionary with mixed-type values, e.g. make this work:

```rust
let dict = [ ("num", 8), ("str", "asd") ].into_py_dict(py);
```

?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not a user of `pyo3`, but from Rust's point of view the problem is that you try to make a heterogeneous array, which is prohibited anyway. To solve it you may try to convert it into a homogeneous array by utilizing [`PyObject`](https://docs.rs/pyo3/0.12.1/pyo3/prelude/type.PyObject.html) type of the crate. I can't test if the next snippet works and I'm not sure if you can make it simpler, but the idea holds:

```
let key_vals: &[(&str, PyObject)] = [ ("num", 8.to_object()), ("str", "asd".to_object()) ]
let dict = key_vals.into_py_dict(py);
```

Comment: Might need some more conversion as `ToPyObject` returns a `type PyObject = Py<PyAny>`, but it's unclear that *that* implements `ToPyObject`, so you may need to get the `PyAny` out of the `Py` somehow.

Comment: Thanks! It seems that the idea works. This prints what I would expect:
https://gist.github.com/tungli/e9afbb82abce2faf8de8635b37713e6a

Answer (score 6):

Just for completion -- [Alex Larionov's idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64694411/how-to-create-a-heterogeneous-python-dict-in-rust-with-pyo3/64697475#64697475) works!

The working code snippet is:

```rust
let key_vals: Vec<(&str, PyObject)> = vec![
    ("num", 8.to_object(py)), ("str", "asd".to_object(py))
];
let dict = key_vals.into_py_dict(py);
```

The whole main [here](https://gist.github.com/tungli/e9afbb82abce2faf8de8635b37713e6a).

This additional import is needed:

```rust
use pyo3::types::IntoPyDict;
```

Also, just a remark, if you happen to need to put a Python `None` value into the dictionary, where `.to_object(py)` fails, use:

```rust
py.None()
```

instead.

Variable `py` is the `pyo3::Python` object.